# Cant add new record to database

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add new records into my database via php but I can not get it to work. I Triple checked all my values, the correct table/row names but still not working. Perhaps a second pair of eyes can see my issue.

Here is my form...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" border="0">
        <?php
            echo '<textarea name="addname" cols="20" rows="1">Enter new name</textarea>';
            echo '<textarea name="adddescription" cols="110" rows="5">Enter new Description</textarea>';
            echo '<textarea name="addpagetitle" cols="100" rows="3">Enter new Page Title</textarea>';
            echo '<textarea name="addpagetags" cols="100" rows="2">Enter new Page Tags</textarea>';
            echo '<textarea name="addmetadescription" cols="100" rows="5">Enter new Meta Description</textarea>';
        ?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Here us my button...

```
<input type="hidden" name="addedit" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="add" name="add" style="background:#e5f9bb; cursor:pointer;  cursor:hand;" />
```

Here is my function for adding new record.

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])){
    $newname = $_POST['addname'];
    $newdescription = $_POST['adddescription'];
    $newpagetitle = $_POST['addpagetitle'];
    $newmetakey = $_POST['addpagetags'];
    $newmetadescription = $_POST['addmetadescription'];


    //adds new destination and info...
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO destination(name, description, page_title, page_tags,  page_description_tag) VALUES ('$newname','  $newdescription','$newpagetitle','$newmetakey','$newmetadescription')");


}
```

Also I wanted to double check that If when added, does sql assign the new record a primary key which in my case would be IDDestination. Or do I need to code that in myself? which could be my problem. Thanks!

Comment: 1 row textarea is silly just use an input type text.

Comment: So what is actually failing?  Have you looked at the result of your `mysql_query()` call to see if it is actually working? BTW, you should not be using deprecated `mysql_*` functions and you should be looking into how to prevent against SQL injection, which you are currently vulnerable to.

Comment: The part that is failing is saving the new record to my destination table in my database. I used var_dump($_POST) to check my values. I also see a new line in my database table but it is all NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your query to this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO destination(name, description, page_title, page_tags,  page_description_tag) VALUES ('". $newname ."','".  $newdescription ."','". $newpagetitle ."','". $newmetakey ."','". $newmetadescription ."')");
```

For your primary key you can use auto increment (sorry, may be I bad understand your last question)

Comment: And don't forget about sql-injection)